# how to render svg file in iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, quartz-2d

i wrote code to display any type of file like pdf,svg,etc.But unfortunately my code is working with only pdf.the code is like this

```
-(void)drawRect : (CGRect)rect {
CGPDFPageRef myPage;
NSString * pathToPdfDoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@ "pdfdoc" ofType:@ "pdf"];
NSURL * pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPdfDoc];
// NSLog(@"%@",pdfUrl);
CGPDFContentStreamRef myContentStream;
document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
// NSLog(@"%@",[document description]);
if (document) {
    int numOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);
    // NSLog(@"%d",numOfPages);
    CGPDFPageRef myPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, pgno);
    myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(myPage);
    // CGPDFOperatorTableRef myTable;
    // myScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate (myContentStream, myTable, NULL);
    // CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
    // page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 2);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, [self bounds].size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx,
                       CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPage, kCGPDFCropBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

}

initially i thought that if i change "pathForResources:ofType"method  argument is svg it will works but it is not working, can any one suggest me modifications.
thank you

Comment: SVG is a completely different file format than PDF.  Why would you expect that a CGPDFDocument would be able to handle it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG images in an iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251029/svg-images-in-an-iphone-application)

Comment: just now checked thank you all!!!!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you may want to have a look at [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As per the comments to the question:*

- Learn more about using SVG images on the iPhone
  Check out [SVG images in an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251029/143). The gist is, use a `UIWebView`,
- SVG is not PDF

Answer (score 0):

Checkout

> SVGKit SVGKit is a Cocoa framework for rendering SVG files natively:
>   it's fast and powerful.
>   https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit#readme