# Keep many images in an iOS app

Tags: ios, image

I want to make an iOS app. This app will have over 200 images, each with different sizes (500x500[maybe smaller] and less). What is the best method to keep them, having a smaller app size?

I think about optimizing their sizes for web in photoshop, but still the app will have a big size if I want to keep and a respectful quality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if you can do this for your app, but you can download them from the internet once the user installed your app. This way you can keep the size of the package as small as possible (I assume you talk about non-critical images, that can be obtain afterwards).

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can use SVG instead of bitmaps, of course if applicable:

[how to render svg file in iphone and ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255976/how-to-render-svg-file-in-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: SVG is not applicable. The images are photos with objects, animals and others. I thought about the idea of downloading them from web, but this way the app size will grow in time. I am searching an optimal way to store them.

Comment: @SpartakusMd In this case you can implement a cache system with a certain size, maybe an option for the user, and when the limit is reached, you could delete some older files. Or you can store some small preview of the images and get the real size if the user want to see the full size.

Comment: I also thought about something like this. I'll accept this as answer. @asalic, do you know a tutorial or an article, something like this to learn about how to implement the cache?

Comment: @SpartakusMd I didn't use any, but one of my colleagues says SDWebImage works pretty well. Here is the link for the project: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage Hope this helps in your case.

Comment: @SpartakusMd And I see it is on SO too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703877/is-there-a-framework-for-image-caching-on-ios